# Filtering on optional data?

Tags: rdf, sparql

How can I filter on optional values in SPARQL, while *keeping* results where the optional value isn't present?  E.g., in the following data there are three books, and the third has no price:

```
:book1 a :Book ; :hasPrice 10.
:book2 a :Book ; :hasPrice 20.
:book3 a :Book.
```

How can I select books that either have a price less than 15 or have no price at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select ?book ?price where { 
  ?book a :Book .
  optional { ?book :hasPrice ?price }
  filter ( !bound(?price) || ?price < 15 )
}
```

```
------------------
| book   | price |
==================
| :book3 |       |
| :book1 | 10    |
------------------
```

Comment: Thanks, same solutions as I figured out, but the values are stored as strings in the triplestore I querying against - that's the problem, actually.

Comment: @TWdorado Then just cast it to a float: `filter( !bound(?price) || xsd:double(?price) < 15 )`.  You didn't show strings in your data, though;  you showed xsd:integer types.  Note that `"15"^^xsd:integer` is not a string, it's an integer (in case that's what you're seeing in your data).

Comment: you're right. I broke down this problem from another one so I didn't see the problem with the strings earlier. And thanks for the cast tip, didn't know that yet.